# Posting to my FB page as the page owner/admin, not my profile name/id

Tags: facebook, api, feed

I have attempted to find an answer vis-a-vis the FB api, Google and this forum.

What I would like to know is what type of a value do I use for the 'from' field when posting to /PAGE/feed using the FB api.

I began including a 'picture' field and now posts to my page are happening as my fb account and not the page like it normally does.

Comment: You don't have to supply a `from` parameter. The only thing that makes a difference about who posted the message is the access token you use. For the post to be done as the page, you'll have to use a page access token.

Answer (score 0):

You must first obtain the page access token before you can post as the page. You're going to need the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions too. To get the page access token, you should run the request using the page administrator's account.

assuming you've done the login and permission (scope) setting correctly, the following code might give you an idea of how this works. assuming $page_id is the variable holding your page's ID number.

```
<?php
    if ($me)
    {
        $pageAccessToken = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'?fields=access_token');
        if (isset($pageAccessToken['access_token']))
        {
            // switch to use page token instead of user token
            $facebook->setAccessToken($pageAccessToken['access_token']);

            // setup your post
            $params = array('message' => "This is a test post",
                            'picture' => "http://nypsit.edu.sg/images/nypsit.jpg",
                            'name'  => "NYP SIT Homepage",
                            'link' => "http://www.nyp.edu.sg/sit/school-of-information-technology",
                            'description' => "Nanyang Polytechnic - School of Information Technology"
                            );

            // post to page timeline
            $status = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed', 'POST', $params);

            // check if post successful
            if (isset($status['id']))
            {
                echo "<h3>Message posted to page timeline!!!</h3>";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I already have the code in place which is functioning. The problem is I added a 'picture' parameter to my array and now FB is posting as me and not the page. I have not tried 'name' or 'from' yet because the api doc for feed does not declare what type of value should be passed as an argument. According to this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/.... 'from' is what I am after as it details who left the message. 'name' apparently only gives a name to the link. What I really want to know is does 'from' expect a string or an int.

Comment: @Lix, thank you. Yes after I stripped the args to just the original message and a 'picture', the code begin to work again as it had. For some reason it did not like the 'link' flag. I didn't have time to get intimate with things but it will do for now.   [@]Zen-Leow, I really like your implementation of the usage of fetching the access_token, I couldn't find a solid reference so I used a bit of a different workaround. Voting both solutions up (can't up vote since I am a noob here, too bad). Thank you all!!!!!!

Comment: And btw @Zen-Low, idk if that was  a jab w/ the link the CS program but I have my degree in CS and working on my second in MeCE... Is your degree even valid in America?

Comment: @CourtneyHall I'm a lecturer in that Polytechnic, our graduates get diplomas. For degree, I believe any degree from Singapore Universities are valid in America. Just check out the ranking and you'll see why. :)

Comment: I am not sure why I felt as if I was being attacked. I have had to learn to read between the lines in this industry. People can be brilliant but equally nasty all at the same vein. I have had co-workers say and do very disgusting things only to have HR turn a blind eye leaving me to fend for myself. My apologies for thinking that your reference to the institution in which you educate was a personal attack against me. I thought that you were trying to be funny... With that said, I apologize if I offended you Professor! BTW that code does not work as you expect or the fb doc states...

Comment: BTW, that example from up above does not work as expected. I have found some posts about issues with not being able to post a pic and a link simultaneously. Check it out. I have to go eat, the family is calling. Again my apologies. Regards.